# Filtering parent collection by grandchildren properties in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, linq-to-entities

Using EF core 5 and ASP.NET Core 3.1, I am trying to get a filtered collection based on a condition on its grandchildren collection.
I have the following entities:

```
public class Organisation
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? OrganisationId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public partial class Customer
{
        [Key]
        public uint Id { get; set; }
        public int? EmployerId { get; set; }
        public int? OrganisationId { get; set; }
        public List<TimecardProperties> TimecardsProperties { get; set; }
}

public partial class TimecardProperties
{     
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? EmployerId { get; set; }
        public int? Week { get; set; }
        public short? Year { get; set; }
}
```

The goal is to get all Organisations that have at least one customer and the customer has at least 1 timecard property that is in `week=34` and `year=2021`.

So far I have tried the following:

```
////necessary join to get Organisations for user id
            IQueryable<Organisation> ouQuery = (from cou in _dbContext.Organisations
                           join uou in _dbContext.table2 on cou.OrganisationId equals uou.OrganisationId                           
                           where uou.UsersId == int.Parse(userId)                          
                           select cou)
                           .Where(cou => cou.Customers.Where(c => c.TimecardsProperties.Count > 0).Any())
                           .Include(cou => cou.Customers.Where(c => c.TimecardsProperties.Count > 0))
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.TimecardsProperties.Where(tc => tc.tWeek == 34 && tc.Year > 2020))
                             ;
```

This returns a `organisation` list that each have a `customers` list but some customers have a count of `timecards` 0. I don't want to have `organisation` in the returned list that does not have at least one item in the `timecards` collection.

Also, it is too slow, and if I try to filter the produced list its even
slower (over 15 seconds)

I have also tried a raw sql query on the `organisation db context` but it is again very slow:

```
select distinct count(id) from organisation a where organisation_id  in (
select organisation_id from customers where employer_id in (select distinct employer_id from timecards a
inner join timecard_components b on a.id=b.timecards_id
where week IN(
34) and year in (2021,2021) and invoice !=0 and type = 'time'
 group by employer_id, week)
);
```

In general, I want to know the the total
count of the returned `organisation` collection for pagination (so I don't need to include all attributes of each entity)
as well as return only a part of the *correct* results, which satisfy the conditions,
an `organisation` list that has at least 1 `timecards` in
their `customers` by executing the query in the end like so:

```
ouQuery.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
```

I have also tried the EntityFramework.Plus and projection with no results.
How could I write this to achieve getting the total count of the `organisation` list and a part of these results (first 10) to display to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use navigation properties. This is the query you want:

```
var orgsQuery = dbContext.Organizations
    .Where( o => o.Customers.Any( c =>
        c.TimecardProperties.Any( tp =>
            tp.Year = 2021
            && tp.Week = 34 ) ) );
```

Add includes and other predicates as needed

Comment: I have issues with this, after including this: ````.Include(cou => cou.Customers).ThenInclude(c => c.TimecardsProperties.Where(tc => tc.Week == 34 && tc.Year > 2020)) ````
 which is the loading time, when I call ````ToListAsync()```` it loads for over 10 seconds (even ````CountAsync()```` goes for 7-8 sec ). Because afterwards I have to remove the customers that have a ````count=0```` of ````TimecardProperties````. Thank you.

Comment: Try adding an index to the table backing `TimecardProperties` that includes the FK to `Customer` as well as the `Week` and `Year` field

Comment: There is an index in the `TimecardProperties`, `[Index(nameof(EmployerId), Name = "employer_id")]` as well as in the table (db first approach - reverse engineer)

Comment: Unless that index includes the fields I mentioned, it's useless for this purpose.  Try adding the index I specified to improve performance.

Comment: Adding a new index to the table with these columns really improved the query load time, thank you. Should I do the same when I want for example to sum all the values from a related entity to `TimecardProperties` or adding many indexes is not a good idea?

Comment: Indicies have performance impacts for inserts and updates (where one or more fields is covered by the index) but that's usually only significant if you're inserting/updating at high volume and need minimal latency.  You want indices on fields that are used for joins and predicates/filtering